# Is there a recognized practice for keeping security details in files excluded from version control?

Tags: 7, security, version-control, configuration

As `settings.php` also contains the database connection details and the site key among others, it is excluded from version control in `.gitignore`.

But there some modules, `APC` for instance that require some of their configuration to be added to `settings.php`.

This means that some settings necessary for the site to run correctly may not be present in a site created from a `git clone`.

Is there a standard practice for dealing with this, ie enabling `settings.php` for source control and `include`-ing the security and other settings from different files, or vice versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We split our settings.php file into two separate files:

- **settings.php** (for configuration that applies to all environments)
- **local-settings.php** (for configuration that applies specifically to the current environment)

"settings.php" is stored in version control, while "local-settings.php" is excluded. Each environment has its own version of local-settings.php, which contains its database credentials and other configuration that applies only to that environment.

At the bottom of settings.php, we include the local-settings.php file.

```
/**
 * Check for a local-settings.php in this direcory. Include it if one exists.
 */
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/local-settings.php')) {
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/local-settings.php';
}
```

Comment: Is there an established naming standard or convention for the file name in the Drupal world for doing this?

Comment: I have done some more research and the preferred names seem to be a toss up between local.settings.php and settings.local.php.

Comment: I don't think the name of the file matters much except to make sure it ends in .php (to ensure the contents cannot be read if someone visits the file directly).

Comment: Some kind of standard or convention needs to be in place so folk become aware of the need sooner rather than later. The amount of passwords from all kinds of projects which have wound up in Github repos is considered legion.